# CKEDITOR validation in JQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, ckeditor

i want validate my ckeditor with jquery validation,Validation fire on submit event and give error message on that according message

Web Page:

```
Script:
 jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                                if (element.type === "radio") {
                                    this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
                                } else {
                                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-feedback').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
                                    $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.icon').remove();
                                    $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<span class="icon icon-validation-error"></span>');
                                }
                            },
                            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                                if (element.type === "radio") {
                                    this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                                } else {
                                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
                                    $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.icon').remove();
                                    $(element).closest('.`enter code here`form-group').append('<span class="icon icon-validation-right"></span>');
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="form-name" id="form-name" >

    <textarea class="ckeditor" name="cktext" id="cktext"></textarea>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success">Submit</button>
```

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#form-id").validate(
        {
            ignore: [],
          debug: false,
            rules: { 

                cktext:{
                     required: function() 
                    {
                     CKEDITOR.instances.cktext.updateElement();
                    },


                }
            },
            messages:
                {

                cktext:{
                    required:"Please enter Text",
                                       }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: what to do when there are other hidden fields which doesn't want to be validated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
 CKEDITOR.instances['id'].on('focus', function () {
   //Do something here.
 });
```

you can pass any valid event here.